# Scalatra Basic Authentication for part of an application

Tags: http, scala, basic-authentication, scalatra

I'm trying to figure out how to write an app which has basic authentication enabled for certain URLs. The authenticated part should not have form-based authentication, just the default login I can do easily from Javascript/JQuery. I've seen a [few](http://www.jaredarmstrong.name/2011/08/scalatra-an-example-authentication-app/) [examples](https://gist.github.com/660701) which look complicated and when I try to use them, lot of the stuff is deprecated and in general it seems to be a lot of work to get the example code even to compile now.

So are those examples still the best Scalatra has to offer or is there a simpler way now?

I'm using Scalatra (with scalatra-auth) version 2.1.1.

Answer (score 3):

Found an [easier example](https://gist.github.com/2708163) and got the below code working.

```
package mc.nulty

import org.scalatra.auth.strategy.BasicAuthStrategy.BasicAuthRequest
import org.scalatra._
import scalate.ScalateSupport

class McNultyServlet extends ScalatraServlet with ScalateSupport {

  get("/") {
    basicAuth
    <html>
      <body>
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
        Say <a href="hello-scalate">hello to Scalate</a>.
      </body>
    </html>
  }

  notFound {
    // remove content type in case it was set through an action
    contentType = null
    // Try to render a ScalateTemplate if no route matched
    findTemplate(requestPath) map { path =>
      contentType = "text/html"
      layoutTemplate(path)
    } orElse serveStaticResource() getOrElse resourceNotFound()
  }

  protected def basicAuth() = {
    val req = new BasicAuthRequest(request)

    def notAuthenticated() {
      response.setHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic realm=\"%s\"" format "mc-nulty")
      halt(401, "Unauthenticated")
    }

    if(!req.providesAuth) {
      notAuthenticated
    }
    if(!req.isBasicAuth) {
      halt(400, "Bad Request")
    }
    val user = DAO.validateLoginPassword(req.username, req.password)
    if (user != null)
      response.setHeader("REMOTE_USER", "user.id")
    else {
      notAuthenticated
    }
    Option(user)
  }

  object DAO {
    def validateLoginPassword(username: String, password: String) : User = {
      if (username.equals("foo")) new User()
      else null
    }
  }
  class User(val id:String = "dummyid") {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's now a Scalatra guide on authentication which covers the basic auth case you're looking for. See http://scalatra.org/2.2/guides/http/authentication.html

Scalatra's auth integrations should not have changed between Scalatra 2.1.1 (which you're using) and the soon-to-be-released Scalatra 2.2.0, so the guide should still be valid for you.